# Karate remove null value and the key from nested array list returned from DB

Tags: karate

for example, I get the below list when querying from the DB
[
{
"a":"123",
"b": "CAT"
}
{
"a": "456",
"b": null
}
{
"a":"789",
"b": "DOG"
}
{
"a":"134",
"b": null
}
]

I want to remove the key and value when the value is null
Expected
[
{
"a":"123",
"b": "CAT"
}
{
"a": "456"
}
{
"a":"789",
"b": "DOG"
}
{
"a":"134"
}

]

Please can someone help with this request, The reason I want to remove the null is the response which comes from the API ignores the null in the DB and looks like the expected, I have to match the response and the DB. Thanks in advance, Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `karate.filter()` is for, please search for it (and read) the docs.

And in the latest version, this short-cut will also work:

```
* def list = [ { "a":"123", "b": "CAT" } { "a": "456", "b": null } { "a":"789", "b": "DOG" } { "a":"134", "b": null } ]
* def list = list.filter(x => x.b != null)
* print list
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you for your answer, I tried your solution by updating the project to the new version, The whole object is removed including the attribute and the value for "a". I tried a different approach and it worked. Thank you once again for your support.